# Can derived class access private static member function

Tags: c++, static, private

I have a code like this, it seems it works. I have no idea why private static method can be accessed like this.

```
class Base
{
   public:
      static void f(){std::cout<<"in base\n";};
};

class Derived:private Base
{
};


int main()
{

   Derived::f();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that say that `f()` is `public`?

Comment: @tom502, class `Base` is privately inherited however. `f` shouldn't be visible to non-members of `Derived`.

Comment: i think f() can not be accessed like this

Comment: What compiler you are using? `Derived::f()` may be accessible only from friends of `Derived` (or as `Base::f()`). `main` doesn't seem to be a friend of `Derived`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refused by all compilers I've tried (several g++ version, como online, IBM xlC) excepted sun CC.  My guess is that it is a bug in your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

No, `f` should not be accessible via `Derived` (except a member function) as `Base` is inherited privately. GCC correctly reports this error:

```
temp.cpp:6: error: ‘static void Base::f()’ is inaccessible
temp.cpp:17: error: within this contex
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code `f()` is privately inherited so you can't access it like this

```
int main()
{

   Derived::f();
   return 0;
}
```

accessibility error for `f()`

Answer (score 0):

***In Private Inheritance, All the members of the Base Class become Private memebers of the Derived Class***

Class Derived derives Privately from Class Base, Hence the member function Base::f() becomes Private member of the Derived class. A Private member of an class cannot be accessed from outside the class(only accessible inside class member functions) Hence the code cannot compile cleanly.

The fact that f() is static function has no effect on these basic rules of inheritance and Access specifiers. A non static member function in Base would show the same behavior.

If your compiler compiles this code then it has a bug which you should report.